# How to return an HTTP response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, http-error

I have a pop-up banner that looks something like this:

```
if (confirm("Banner message")) {
  //do something if they accept
}
else {
  //do something else if they don't accept
}
```

If the user does not accept, I want to return a 403 Forbidden, preferably in a way that will get picked up by my httpd logs. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`confirm` is an extension to JavaScript provided to JS by browsers that runs, client-side, in a webpage.

You cannot (directly) send an HTTP response in reaction to it, because it is running in an HTTP *client*.

If you want to log something in your server logs, then you need to make an HTTP **request** to your server.

This would typically be done using the `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` APIs. If you want a standard 403 Forbidden error to be displayed to the user, then you can assign a URL to `location` that your server will return a 403 for instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a 403 Response, you need to request this from the server, since it's an error message sent by the server. I suggest you use `window.location = "/someSpecialPath";` and make a 403 error using .htacces or something to that path:

`deny from all`